# Display the list of user's comments + the post title + date

Tags: php, comments, comment-form, wp-user-query, wp-comment-query

I am trying to display the current user's ALL comments in a specific page and I'm using this code (uses a shortcode): https://blog.ashfame.com/2011/01/show-recent-comments-particular-user-wordpress/

And have modified it:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Show Recent Comments by a particular user
Plugin URI: http://blog.ashfame.com/?p=876
Description: Provides a shortcode which you can use to show recent comments by a particular user
Author: Ashfame
Author URI: http://blog.ashfame.com/
License: GPL
Usage: 
*/

add_shortcode ( 'show_recent_comments', 'show_recent_comments_handler' );

function show_recent_comments_handler( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        "count" => 10,
        "pretty_permalink" => 0
        ), $atts ));

    $output = ''; // this holds the output
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
            'number' => $count, // how many comments to retrieve
            'status' => 'approve'
            );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );
        if ( $comments )
        {
            $output.= "<ul>\n";
            foreach ( $comments as $c )
            {
            $output.= '<li>';
            if ( $pretty_permalink ) // uses a lot more queries (not recommended)
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
            else
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/?p='.$c->comment_post_ID.'#comment-'.$c->comment_ID.'">';           
            $output.= $c->comment_content;
            $output.= ', Post Name: '.get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
            $output.= '</a>, Posted on: '. mysql2date('m/d/Y', $c->comment_date, $translate);
            $output.= "</li>\n";
            }
            $output.= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output.= "<h2>You should be logged in to see your comments. Make sense?</h2>";
        $output.= '<h2><a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/wp-login.php?redirect_to='.get_permalink().'">Login Now &rarr;</a></h2>';
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```

It possible to display the comments like this:

- Post title (title of the post where the user leaved comment)

  - comment excerpt (This is a comment I made on......)
  - comment date
- Post title (title of the post where the user leaved comment)

  - comment excerpt (This is a comment I made on......)
  - comment date
- Post title (title of the post where the user leaved comment)

  - comment excerpt (This is a comment I made on......)
  - comment date

Because it doesn't look good using my current code, see screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/xd8qmc

Is it also possible to paginate the comments?

Comment: You didn't include the screenshot. But it sounds like this is just a styling question, and you've got the WordPress-specific parts working?

Comment: Yes, the styling only. Here's the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/xd8qmc

Answer (score 0):

add this snippet for according your needed:

```
add_shortcode ( 'show_recent_comments', 'show_recent_comments_handler' );

function show_recent_comments_handler( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        "count" => 10,
        "pretty_permalink" => 0
        ), $atts ));

    $output = ''; // this holds the output
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
            'number' => $count, // how many comments to retrieve
            'status' => 'approve'
            );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );
        if ( $comments )
        {
            $output.= "<ul>\n";
            foreach ( $comments as $c )
            {
            $output.= '<li>';

            $output.= 'Post Name: '.get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
            $output.= "<ul>";

            if ( $pretty_permalink ) // uses a lot more queries (not recommended)
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
            else
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/?p='.$c->comment_post_ID.'#comment-'.$c->comment_ID.'">';        
            $output.='<li>'. $c->comment_content .'</li>';
            $output.= '</a><li> Posted on: '. mysql2date('m/d/Y', $c->comment_date, $translate).'</li>';
            $output.= '</ul>';
            $output.= "</li>\n";
            }
            $output.= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output.= "<h2>You should be logged in to see your comments. Make sense?</h2>";
        $output.= '<h2><a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/wp-login.php?redirect_to='.get_permalink().'">Login Now &rarr;</a></h2>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it also possible to paginate the comments?